# Raster data does not clip to the vector polygon boundary

Tags: raster

I am trying to clip a raster to vector polygon. I am using "Extract by Mask" tool and my output raster layer is, what seems like, randomly cut off in the middle. My processing extent is set appropriately, my coordinate system is the same for both layers, and I have about 10 other raster layers that I did the same thing for and they worked perfectly. I have no idea how to diagnose this problem. Any ideas? [image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's just not the extent of the raster? The clip suspiciously follows the US/Canada boundary both near Alaska and southern Canada...

Comment: Okay, so that is my bad, i didn't explain completely. yes, the south border of the raster is correct, i am concerned about the portion to the east. The raster data is only for CANADA, but its for all of Canada. The portion that is missing is not the south, the data does not extend that far, but the portion that is missing is East Canada.

Comment: And you're 100% sure that it exists? I.e. when you plot the raster it covers all of Canada?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure, i just added an image of the original raster and the vector polygon i am trying to clip it to.  As you can see the raster extends all the way to the east, but when I clip it to the vector polygon the output is truncated. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Is the clipped raster 4gb? You might need to turn on the BIGTIFF option...just spitballing here.